# An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaConventions?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, aspectj

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaConventions After downloading AspectJ development Tools in Eclipse.
I am using spring boot.

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough informations so others can better understand. Try to include the console error in the question.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Eclipse version? AJDT version? AJDT update site or download source?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
turns out to be a bug that AspectJ Development Tools from the marketplace not up to date with the Eclipse 4.21
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575897#c10

Comment: Hey, you did some research and found my answer in the Bugzilla ticket. Happy it works for you. BTW, a few days ago together with AspectJ 1.9.9 I also released a refreshed AJDT version for 4.23 (2022-03).